# Как правильно выбрать БД для проекта

Tags: проектирование, база-данных, yii

Допустим есть проект, естественно на стадии проектирования.

Как обычно есть дефолтная БД Mysql - как обычно.

И дальше никто не парится о том как и что будет работать.

Вопрос:

"**Исходя из каких тестов/соображений/документации и прочего нужно/можно выбирать нужную БД**"

Что будет:

- Частые запросы на сторонний сервер
- Запись данных ответов от сервера
- Обновление/получение информации из БД
- Сколько будет инфы представить пока трудно, запросов на запись в день во все таблицы около 100-500К. С таким числом мускул справится.

Но продолжим:

- У нас есть другая ситуация с униками, коотрых 10-100-300К в сутки.
- Кол-во записей в БД возрастает
- Кол-во информации которая должна быть видна всем - должна быть доступна сиюминутно, т.е. постоянно висеть в памяти (Redis)/
- Хранить нужно много XML
- Быстрый поиск информации
- Хорошая связь между таблицами
- Возможность кэширования запросов.
- Возможность Бэкапов.

**Да и вообще что выбрать NoSql или Sql БД?**

Как их затестить с какими-либо данными и понять результаты, но за короткий срок, чтобы не вдаваться в глубокие познания каждой БД.

На чем тестировать? Какими программами? Запросами? т.е. на что ориентироваться разработчикам при описании проекта и выбора какую БД использовать? 
Внятно объяснить начальству и/или заказчику почему именно эта БД, а не другая.

Раз разговор про Yii в общем контексте, то по идее переход с одной БД на другую не должен составить проблем т.е. у нас MVC приложение, которое работает с моделями, и моделям без разницы какая БД, ну может быть что-то и придется подкрутить но не в глобальных масштабах.
 И как быть если все таки в процессе эксплуатации, разработчики поймут что будет нужна другая БД, и без потерь перейти на другую?

Наверное вот такой вопрос, но **скорее всего это обсуждение** т.к. многие сталкивались/сталкиваются с такими вопросами.

**//upd вопроса, нужны еще вещи для решения данной задачи**

Comment: > Хранить нужно много XML

В базе SQL ?

вот за это я в свое время перестал уважать команду разработки HSP Сomplete.

Comment: Ну да, и просто данные и XML, да не суть что хранить. Вопрос немного в другом т.к. хранить мы в БД можем дофига чего, от 0 и 1 до файлов, ссылок на файлы, ведение статистики и прочее, прочее, прочее.

Comment: тогда наверное вам подойдет noSql mongo например, т.к. оно документоориентированное. 

просто хотел подчеркнуть, что хранить XML  - мало осмысленное дело, особенно если оно будет парситься самим приложением.

Answer (score 0):

[@Shrek](/users/4597/shrek), а вопрос бэкапов без остановки базы Вас не волнует?

IMHO это очень важный момент для выбора, если речь не идет о возможности остановки системы на ночь (с прихватыванием выходных). Обычно, насколько мне известно, такая фича есть у коммерческих СУБД (в отличие от халявы).

Кстати, халявные снапшоты мне тоже известны только на уровне уже довольно дорогих устройств хранения.

Иначе, всю эту прелесть с бекапом без потери целостности данных надо проектировать на уровне прикладного кода  (причем сразу, после написания первой версии будет уже поздно).

Comment: Ну как вариант бэкапы нужны. 

Я же не все написал в вопрос, можно дополнить его :)

Comment: А я просто решил заострить Ваше внимание на этом, пока проектирование не зашло слишком далеко.

Comment: Добавил про бэкапы.

В данный момент это все вопросы больше для всех нежели для моего проекта, но почему и не воспользоваться каким-нибудь шаблоном :), который мы совместными усилиями и напишем

Answer (score 0):

Выбирайте ту, которую знаете лучше всего.

Например, правильная настройка [Mysql](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2009/04/23/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-mysql-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/) и [Postgres](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2009/05/01/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-postgresql/) позволят получить очень высокую производительность.

Comment: @Den Golotyuk Tnx.